# SPL Autoloading best practices

Tags: php, spl, autoloader, spl-autoloader

In my include_path on the server-side I have a reference to a pear directory, in '/usr/share/pear/'. Within my applications I include files from a common library, living in '/usr/share/pear/library/' with `require_once 'library/file.php'`.

I've recently started using the spl autoloader, I noticed in the loader function you have to determine the logic with which to include the file. My first way of doing this was trying to include a file and suppressing it with `@` to see if it would fail, e.g. `@include 'library/file.php'` however I think mostly because I read a lot about `@` being a bad practice I decided to manually do the work myself by exploding `get_include_path` by the `PATH_SEPARATOR` and seeing if the directory is what I want it to be, then doing a `file_exists` and including it.

Like so:

```
function classLoader( $class ) {
    $paths = explode( PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path() );
    $file = SITE_PATH . 'classes' . DS . $class . '.Class.php';
    if ( file_exists( $file) == false ) 
    {
        $exists = false;
        foreach ( $paths as $path ) 
        {
            $tmp = $path . DS . 'library' . DS . 'classes' . DS . $class . '.Class.php';
            if ( file_exists ( $tmp ) ) 
            {
            $exists = true;
            $file = $tmp;
            }
        }
        if ( !$exists ) { return false; }
    }
    include $file;
}

spl_autoload_register('classLoader');
```

Did I go the wrong route? Should I have just done the `@include` business or am I doing it somewhat in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing that the [Habari project autoloader](http://trac.habariproject.org/habari/browser/trunk/htdocs/system/index.php) does that's interesting is cache the whole class file list in memory so that it's not doing disk searches for the files every time a class is requested.

Essentially, you declare a static inside your `__autoload()` that holds an array of all of the class files, indexed by the class that will cause them to load.  For example, the code would use Dir or `glob()` to generate this static array:

```
$class_files = array(
  'user' => '/var/www/htdocs/system/classes/user.class.php',
);
```

Then you simply include `$class_files[$class]` to get the correct file.  This is nice and speedy because it gets the catalog from the disk all at once, rather than generating the list or searching for a specific filename each time a new class is referenced. (You would be surprised how much of a speed difference it makes.)

If the class name isn't a key in the array, you can throw a custom exception or generate a stub/mock class to return.  Also, if you check out the Habari system autoloader, you'll see that Habari implements `__static()` in classes that are autoloaded, which is like a constructor for static classes.

`include_once()` is to be avoided, and the `@` operator is unnecessary if you've checked for the file to include.

Answer (score 1):

I personally go the way using

```
function autoload($class) {
    /* transform class name into filename ... */
    include $class;
}
```

even without the @ to ease debugging (errors are shut down/logged in production)

You might also be interested in the related discussion on the PHP developer list: http://marc.info/?t=125787162200003&r=1&w=2

Comment: Isn't the spl autoloading the more practical and modern method? Or are they basically the same thing?